# How to shownicknames instead of foreign key in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, data-analysis

So I'm practicing queries on SQL for educational purposes and I'm running queries from an NBA Basketball dataset. I want to make a query that will show me a date, home team, away team, and winner column. I can easily do this with this query:

```sql
SELECT game_id, SUBSTRING(date,0,11) AS Date_Only, team_id_home, team_id_away, team_id_winner
FROM game
```

However, these only show the id's of the teams. I don't want to see the foreign key id's of the teams, I want to see the nicknames for the teams which there's a separate table where the team id's and their nicknames are. How am I able to show the nicknames instead of the foreign keys? I've thought of a few things but there may be an easier way to do this. Appreciate the help.
[image: query result]
[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: Add a JOIN to the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query needs to join the table that contains the nicknames so that you can select the appropriate column, e. g.

```
SELECT game_id, SUBSTRING(date,0,11) AS Date_Only, 
   home_team.nickname AS home_team_nickname,
   away_team.nickname AS away_team_nickname,
   winner_team.nickname AS winner_team_nickname
FROM game 
  INNER JOIN team home_team ON game.team_id_home = home_team.team_id
  INNER JOIN team away_team ON game.team_id_away = away_team.team_id
  INNER JOIN team winner_team ON game.team_id_winner = winner_team.team_id
;
```

Comment: Ahh I knew there'd be a `JOIN` in there, just didn't know what part of the syntax. But thank you, I didn't know I could reference a column like that with `column_name.column_name`. So because I am referencing the `game` column in the `JOIN` statement, only then can I do the `home_team.nickname`? Would that imply that the `FROM` statement executes first?

Comment: It's not `column_name.column_name` but `table_name.column_name`. Yes, the FROM statement is evaluated first. It basically forms a table from which you can select the desired columns. I explained JOINs a little more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73400986/19657183).

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I see the 'table_name.column_name' syntax in the `INNER JOIN`s portion of the query, but in the `SELECT` statement for `home_team.nickname`, the `home_team.` part isn't a table, it's a column. That's the part that confuses me

Comment: `home_team` is just an alias for the table `team` in that specific JOIN. It's necessary to give it an alias because the same table `team` is joined multiple times. Otherwise there would be no chance to distinguish between the different joined teams. If you look at the query: the first joined team was aliased by `home_team`, the second by `away_team` and the third by `winner_team`.

Comment: Understood, thank you so much! Will look at the material you sent as well.